# Filtering out good company result based on quarter date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `'QuarterlyReport'` which has multiple company's quarterly profit figures with the following column `'CompanyName'`, `'QuarterEndDate'` & `'Profit'`

```
|CompanyName|QuarterEndDate|Profit|
|---------------------------------|
|A          |2013-06-30    |29878 |
|A          |2013-09-30    |33712 |
|A          |2013-12-31    |60764 |
|A          |2014-03-31    |260734|
|B          |2013-06-30    |-1234 |
|B          |2013-09-30    |0     |
|B          |2013-12-31    |20114 |
|B          |2014-03-31    |-984  |
...
```

I am trying to construct a MySQL query to see which company has a profit performance which increases in every consecutive quarters (Q4>Q3>Q2>Q1), with a 1 year (4 quarters) date range.

In the case of example above, only Company 'A' will meet this requirement and shall be return as the query's result

Currently I only able to construct query for (Q4>0 AND Q3>0 AND Q2>0) using follow MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT q.CompanyName, q.QuarterEndDate, q.Profit FROM `QuarterlyReport` q) a
WHERE a.QuarterEndDate >= '2013-06-30' AND
a.QuarterEndDate < '2014-06-30' AND
a.CompanyName IN (SELECT CompanyName FROM `QuarterlyReport` WHERE 
a.CompanyName IN (SELECT Q4.CompanyName FROM `QuarterlyReport` AS Q4 WHERE Q4.QuarterEndDate = '2014-03-31' AND Q4.Profit > '0') AND
a.CompanyName IN (SELECT Q3.CompanyName FROM `QuarterlyReport` AS Q3 WHERE Q3.QuarterEndDate = '2013-12-31' AND Q3.Profit > '0') AND
a.CompanyName IN (SELECT Q2.CompanyName FROM `QuarterlyReport` AS Q2 WHERE Q2.QuarterEndDate = '2013-09-30' AND Q2.Profit > '0') AND
a.CompanyName IN (SELECT Q1.CompanyName FROM `QuarterlyReport` AS Q1 WHERE Q1.QuarterEndDate = '2013-06-30' AND Q1.Profit > '0')
GROUP BY a.CompanyName ORDER BY a.CompanyName ASC
```

Can anyone suggest some idea on how to archive my targeted query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM
(
  SELECT CompanyName, 
         MAX(CASE WHEN QUARTER(QuarterEndDate) = 2 THEN Profit END) q1,
         MAX(CASE WHEN QUARTER(QuarterEndDate) = 3 THEN Profit END) q2,
         MAX(CASE WHEN QUARTER(QuarterEndDate) = 4 THEN Profit END) q3,
         MAX(CASE WHEN QUARTER(QuarterEndDate) = 1 THEN Profit END) q4
    FROM QuarterlyReport
   WHERE QuarterEndDate >= '2013-06-30' AND QuarterEndDate < '2014-06-30'
   GROUP BY CompanyName
) q
 WHERE q1 < q2 AND q2 < q3 AND q3 < q4
```

Output:

```
| COMPANYNAME |    Q1 |    Q2 |    Q3 |     Q4 |
|-------------|-------|-------|-------|--------|
|           A | 29878 | 33712 | 60764 | 260734 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a5eb/5)** demo

Comment: this is one very efficient query command and very easily modify to suit other filtering requirements!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select q.*
from quarterlyreport q
join
    (
    select      companyname
    from        quarterlyreport
    where       quarterenddate between '2013-06-30' and '2014-06-30'
    group by    companyname
    having      sum(case when quarter(quarterenddate) = 1 then profit else 0 end)
              > sum(case when quarter(quarterenddate) = 4 then profit else 0 end)
            and sum(case when quarter(quarterenddate) = 4 then profit else 0 end)
              > sum(case when quarter(quarterenddate) = 3 then profit else 0 end)
            and sum(case when quarter(quarterenddate) = 3 then profit else 0 end)
              > sum(case when quarter(quarterenddate) = 2 then profit else 0 end)
    ) v
    on q.companyname = v.companyname
```